# What can I do when my supervisor holds me back from publishing my master's thesis?

Tags: thesis, advisor, masters, paper-submission

I just finished my master's thesis in spring and wanted to apply for an award for this master's thesis by the end of this month. However, my supervisor and professor held me back from doing so because they are afraid that journal reviewers will potentially be reluctant to accept a paper when my master's thesis was quite close to the publication in progress. In case I win the award, my thesis will not be openly published, but might be made available to people requesting it. However, a three-page summary of the method and results will be published; but also only in case I win the award.

My supervisor will use parts of my data but is currently analyzing them independently.

Honestly, I am quite frustrated with this outcome since I know that legally, the thesis is my own intellectual property, and that now, "just out of solidarity with my supervisor's work", I am not able to take the chance to spread the word about the great results of my thesis!

Is this ethical academic practice; what would you suggest me to do?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the sentence about "reluctant to publish...". What is "close to the publication in progress"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Buffy I understand that the supervisor fears that having the master's thesis published may lead to journals rejecting a paper based on the thesis on the grounds that the results are already published.